# Display a div for desktop screen size only

Tags: javascript, jquery

Firstly, I'm a newbie. I have this arrow showing to scroll down (I want it to show up after say 10sec) but I only want it for desktop screen size. I don't quite understand why this doesn't work. The console has a problem with 'Unexpected token <=' but I've done my research and this is exactly what I want, not sure where is the problem coming from.
Thanks for help!

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
      $(window).resize(function() {
        if ($(this).width() >= 1824 && <= 768) {
          $('.scroll_down').hide();
        } else {
          $('.scroll_down').show();
        }
      });
        $(function() {
        $(".scroll_down").delay(1000).fadeIn();
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing another `$(this).width()`, it should be:

```
if ($(this).width() >= 1824 && $(this).width() <= 768) {
  ...
```

Also, you may want to look into CSS media queries, you don't really need Javascript for something like this.

Comment: Many thanks. I know it's doable with CSS however, I want to learn as much js as I can while coding what I'm currently coding. Cheers

Comment: Ok :) To give you a quick performance tip: save the window width to a variable and use that, otherwise the browser will be calculating the width twice: `var win_width = $(this).width();` and use that in the if-statement

Comment: Thanks! I also want the element to appear after say 10s from the moment of entering the page. Is this doable with css? If not, then I guess I could use js only for fading it in after the specified time?

Comment: It's possible, but a little more complicated. You'll have to use keyframe animation, fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/x1eaq422/1/

Comment: By the way you can accept the answer by click the 'v' next to it.

Comment: Thanks, I'm an absolute newbie here